# Are there any drawbacks to very large classes as DataModel?

Tags: firebase, data-modeling, datamodel

In my app I have multiple classes I use as part of my DM (data model).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   I have one class called Media which I use for multiple purposes: To help in formatting data as its created and to format it when it is fetched from the firebase.

I have been making changes to the DM and have now come across this dilema. Should I have a ~86 line DM for Media which serves both as a structure for storing data being viewed, and to format data which will be uploaded to DB. Or should I create two classes for each? Each has very similar inits and variables although some are not used in the other...

**Are there drawbacks to having one class for each or to having one larger class with some unused in some situation propertys?**

Comment: This is an OS/language independent question.

Comment: Do you mean language _dependent_? The question is very broad and without some context about language, it's unanswerable

Comment: @rmaddy not necessarily, could swift and iOS dev come with some unique differences thus changing the recommendation?

Comment: @NCT127 I meant independent. The answer applies to scores of languages, not just the original Swift it was tagged.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, you can interpret in any way you like I just want to know which one if any is better than the other. Are there drawbacks to either of the options? Maby slower app or something like that? This is why im aksing

Comment: Better on what basis? Performance? Maintainability? Visual Appeal?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid performance, mainly with some consideration to maintainability and visuals

Comment: Performance in a database facing app is more likely to bad database design / missing indexes / optimisation. Maintainability and Performance are often mutually exclusive. You dropped a hint about Firebase. Firebase vs some other database backend might have different answers

Comment: Ok so in terms of the choice of datamodel if I am using firebase....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that there are brilliant implementations available out of the box to serve as storage, I would not venture into creating one and reinventing the wheel; and if you need to offload object storage, you have the likes of Redis for a start.

So, as long as you can identify a Media uniquely, use a MediaDAO (Data Access Object) to retrieve and persist Media objects from and into a Java `Collection`. If your programming language is not Java, find the equivalents in your language. Assuming these are large objects, you are better off not storing them in heap memory especially if there are thousands of these.

Write a MediaVO (value object) class to format data during creation and also to format data after retrieval. If your programming language is Java, you can inherit or compose with a number of beautiful datastructure implementations built into the language.